# AngularJS: need to fire event every time an ajax call is started

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fire an event on $rootScope every time an ajax call is started.

```
var App = angular.module('MyApp');

App.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    //add a transformRequest to preprocess request
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function () {
        //resolving $rootScope manually since it's not possible to resolve instances in config blocks
        var $rootScope = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$rootScope');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('httpCallStarted');

       var $log = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$log');
       $log.log('httpCallStarted');
    });
});
```

The event 'httpCallStarted' it's not being fired. I suspect that it's not correct to use $rootScope or any other instance service in config blocks. If so, how can I get an event everytime an http call is starting, without having to pass a config object in every time I am making a call?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the calls to angular.injector(['ng']) are where you are going wrong. That is not giving you back the injector function that is actually being used with your application and so when you try to get the $rootScope you are actually getting a different $rootScope than the one you think you are. The only way I know how to get the real injector is through the use of angular.element(someselector).injector() and then you can call .get('$rootScope') on that. I don't know though whether you'll still have issues with doing this in a config block.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could always wrap $http in a service. Since services are only set up one time, you could just have the service factory set up the events for you. It feels a little hackish to me, honestly, but it's a good work around, since Angular doesn't have a global way to do this yet, unless something was added in 1.0.3 that I'm not aware of.

[Here's a plunker of it working](http://plnkr.co/edit/UjlzmT)

And here's the code:

```
app.factory('httpPreConfig', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
    $http.defaults.transformRequest.push(function (data) {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('httpCallStarted');
        return data;
    });
    $http.defaults.transformResponse.push(function(data){ 
        $rootScope.$broadcast('httpCallStopped');
        return data;
    })
    return $http;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, httpPreConfig) {
  $scope.status = [];

  $scope.$on('httpCallStarted', function(e) {
    $scope.status.push('started');
  });
  $scope.$on('httpCallStopped', function(e) {
    $scope.status.push('stopped');
  });

  $scope.sendGet = function (){ 
    httpPreConfig.get('test.json');    
  };
});
```

Comment: It looks nice to me, however how to solve the problem in $resource service, since it depends on $http and not the custom httpPreConfig?

Comment: I *think* after first time you reference this service, it will update the defaults for all calls to $http, even the ones in $resource.

Comment: Well, in fact, there is a very strange behavior. With this code, the ng-view directive stops instantiating controllers. Any idea?

Comment: Not really. Are you seeing any errors in the console? Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: You can check this plunker [http://plnkr.co/edit/BF0wTi](http://plnkr.co/edit/BF0wTi). On line 22 of app.js you have a comment. If you comment the run block, the httpPreConfig instance does never get instantiated, and the ngview works as expected, and my controller is instantiated.

Comment: I'd just go with Ryan O'Neil's answer, honestly. "A" for effort I guess. ;)

Comment: I already know where the issue is. The requestTransform and responseTransform functions should receive as an argument the data and return the data as well, without any transformation. Not doing this, we have side-effects, for example wuth the ng-view.

Comment: You're right. I missed that because I wasn't actually getting anything with my requests.

Comment: HA! Your edit was rejected by some people, but was, in fact correct. I've added it in there. SO is weird sometimes.

Comment: Isn't it better to do the same thing just in Run function?

Comment: is it possible to not `$broadcast` it from `$rootScope`, but `$emit` from local `$scope`?

Comment: @GillBates If you just need to emit from local scope, you don't need to create a wrapped httpService like I did above. You could just call `$scope.$emit` before your `$http` call and in it's resulting `then()` like so: `$scope.$emit('beginHttp'); $http.get('stuff.json').then(function(result) { $scope.$emit('endHttp', result); return result; });`

Comment: @BenLesh Yeah, but in this case it will not be decoupled solution

Comment: @GillBates you could still wrap it then, you'd just need to be able to pass in your local scope on each call so you could $emit from it.

Answer (score 12):

I have verified that this code will work as you expect. As I mentioned above, you are not retrieving the injector that you think you are and need to retrieve the one being used for your app.

```
discussionApp.config(function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(function(data) {
    var $injector, $log, $rootScope;
    $injector = angular.element('#someid').injector();

    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
    $rootScope.$broadcast('httpCallStarted');

    $log = $injector.get('$log');
    $log.log('httpCallStarted');
    return data;
  });
});
```

Comment: To be totally correct you need to receive a data argument and return the some data as well.

Answer (score 12):

Cagatay is right. Better use `$http` interceptors:

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider, $provide) {
    $provide.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, $rootScope) {
        return {
            'request': function (config) {
                // intercept and change config: e.g. change the URL
                // config.url += '?nocache=' + (new Date()).getTime();
                // broadcasting 'httpRequest' event
                $rootScope.$broadcast('httpRequest', config);
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },
            'response': function (response) {
                // we can intercept and change response here...
                // broadcasting 'httpResponse' event
                $rootScope.$broadcast('httpResponse', response);
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            'requestError': function (rejection) {
                // broadcasting 'httpRequestError' event
                $rootScope.$broadcast('httpRequestError', rejection);
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            },
            'responseError': function (rejection) {
                // broadcasting 'httpResponseError' event
                $rootScope.$broadcast('httpResponseError', rejection);
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    });
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});
```

I think `interceptors` works for versions after 1.1.x. 
There was `responseInterceptors` before that version.

Comment: I haven't added an example in my answer, but yes this is exactly what I use in my projects.

Comment: This is a very good answer. I had to use a service (to show/hide the spinner) within the interceptor, but I had used .config to show it, and it's not possible to use service in .config, now with this solution everything works smoothly and just fine!

Comment: I tried this and `$rootScope` was always undefined for me, any idea what might cause that?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is to use an http interceptor. Check [this](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) link