# AngularJS - How to Refresh Controller Property in Timely Manner

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider this very simple app as an example.

### View

```
<div ng-controller="filesController as filesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="file in filesCtrl.files">
        <p>{{file.percent}}% completed of file ID : {{file.id}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Controller

```
app.controller('filesController', function(){
   this.files = files; // the files variable loaded globally as cdata;
});
```

So, this piece of code shows the current progress of files in the server. Now, I need to connect to the server for each file to get percentage timely manner (once in 30 seconds).

I have researched tried to create a service.

### Service

```
app.factory('fileProcessingStatus', ['$http', '$interval', function($http, $interval){
    var service = {};
    service.status = {};
    service.file_id = 0;
    service.isComplete = false;
    service.interval = {};

    service.getCurrentStatus = function(file_id){
        var url = app.ajaxUrl + '?action=file_processing_status&file_id=' + file_id;

        $http.get(url)

        .success(function(data){

                console.log(data);

            if(data == 0){
                service.status = 0;
            }else{
                service.status = data;
                // check data and set isComplete as true when file is finished processing
                if(service.data.status == 'processed'){
                    service.stopChecking();
                }
            }
        })
        .error(function(){
            service.status = 0;
        });

    };

    service.startChecking = function(file_id){
        service.file_id = file_id;
        service.interval = $interval(getCurrentStatus(file_id), 30 * 1000);
    };

    service.stopChecking = function(){
        $interval(service.interval);
    };

}]);
```

The service is intend to send query to server in every 30 seconds **but I do not have any idea how to pass file id to the service**. If I have say 5 files service should be called independently for all 5 files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create checking for each file we need to create individual `$scope` for each file. So the modified code will be something like below.

### Change in View

Need new controller to create different scope for each `file` variable and pass `file` via `ng-init`. Currently I do not know if using `ng-init` is the best practice or not. Feel free enlighten me if you think there is a better solution.

```
<div ng-controller="filesController as filesCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="file in filesCtrl.files">
        <!-- Notice the new controller -->
        <p ng-controller="ProgressUpdate as progressUpdate" ng-init="init(file)">{{file.percent}}% completed of file ID : {{file.id}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Introduce the New Controller (drop the service)

```
// we still need the older one

app.controller('filesController', function(){
   this.files = files; // the files variable loaded globally as cdata;
});

// new controller

 app.controller('ProgressUpdate', ['$http', '$interval', '$scope', function($http, $interval, $scope){
        $scope.status = {};
        $scope.file_id = 0;
        $scope.isComplete = false;
        $scope.interval = {};

        $scope.init = function(file){
            $scope.startChecking(file.id);
            $scope.file = file;
        };

        $scope.startChecking = function(file_id){
            $scope.interval = $interval(function(){
                    $scope.getCurrentStatus(file_id)
                }
                , 30 * 1000);
        };

        $scope.stopChecking = function(){
            $scope.isComplete = true;
            $interval.cancel($scope.interval);
        };

        $scope.getCurrentStatus = function(file_id){
            var url = app.ajaxUrl + '?action=get_file_info&id=' + file_id;

            $http.get(url)

                .success(function(data){
                    var file = $scope.file;

                    if(data == 0){
                        // handle error
                    }else{

                        if(file.status != 'lock'){
                            var processed = data.listing_processed;
                            var percent = (processed/file.total ) * 100;
                            file.percent = percent.toFixed(2);
                        }

                        // check data and set isComplete as true when file is finished processing
                        if(data.status == 'processed'){
                            $scope.stopChecking();
                        }
                    }

                })
                .error(function(){
                    // handle error
                });

        };

    }]);
```

Once we get the `file` inside the `ProgressUpdate` controller we can now create the http request and get data from server. After getting the data successfully we update the `file` variable. Angulars' *two way data binding* takes care the rest that is the view gets automatically updated.

Answer (score 0):

$http doesn't expose the xhr and therefore you cannot register the `onprogress` event.

have a look here [how to add Angular $http event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16023548/how-to-add-angular-http-event-listeners)

Comment: not sure how is that related. I am firing the http request with `$interval`

Comment: xhr (`XMLHttpRequest`) do support what you want: a progress tracker. but angular's `$http` does not support that event. that's why I linked, how you could implement this event yourself, without having to use a hacky `$interval` (which doesn't work)