# How to define hook that will be executed after every XHR?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, angularjs

My use case:
I use Angular with Django backend. Django has nice built-in application called `messages` - it allows to show one-time messages to user, for example "Your account sucessfully activated!". What I want to do is to show them with AJAX - I want to request them after each XHR from a client. Like described in this [article](http://birdhouse.org/blog/2014/02/01/displaying-django-user-messages-with-angular-js/).

How can I make such hook?

Comment: Might want to check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/a/13747488/898423

Answer (score 0):

you should use httpInterceptor to perform certain activity before/after each $http request.

please have a look at this post on how to defined [http interceptor](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

basically define a factory with desired behavior

```
module.factory('myInterceptor', ['$q', 'someAsyncService', function($q, someAsyncService) {
    var requestInterceptor = {
        request: function(config) {
                   //custom logic here
        }
    };

    return requestInterceptor;
}]);
```

and it add it to http interceptor list

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myInterceptor');
}]);
```