# AngularJS: Watching network traffic/xhr requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Does angular/3rd party module for angular has support with network traffic monitoring, and how?

What I would like to establish is something similar to $watch, just for network traffic.

```
$scope.$watch('xhrTraffic', function(newval) {
    newval - true when traffic starts/false when traffic ends
});
```

I want to be able to control when the browser is in network usage and when it's not.

Comment: If you use the `$http` service (and you should) it has a `$httpProvider.interceptors` property that you can use. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746052/angularjs-need-to-fire-event-every-time-an-ajax-call-is-started

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me, that you need something like [this](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth)

---

**UPDATE**

This code will help with managing XHR requests :

```
(function (){
'use strict';
angular.module( 'security.http-interceptor', [] )
    .factory( 'securityInterceptor', ['$injector', '$q', '$rootScope', function ( $injector, $q, $rootScope ){
                  return {
                      'request'       : function ( config ){
                          // do something on success
                          return config;
                      },
                      // optional method
                      'requestError'  : function ( rejection ){
                          // do something on error
                          if ( canRecover( rejection ) ) {
                              return responseOrNewPromise
                          }
                          return $q.reject( rejection );
                      },

                      // optional method
                      'response'      : function ( response ){
                          // do something on success
                          return response;
                      },

                      // optional method
                      'responseError' : function ( rejection ){
                          // do something on error
                          if ( canRecover( rejection ) ) {
                              return responseOrNewPromise
                          }
                          return $q.reject( rejection );
                      }
                  };
              }] )

    // We have to add the interceptor to the queue as a string because the interceptor depends upon service instances that are not available in the config block.
    .config( ['$httpProvider', function ( $httpProvider ){
                 $httpProvider.interceptors.push( 'securityInterceptor' );
             }] );
     }());
```

And link before was an example of AUTH request check.

More about interceptors read [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)